# Excel Countif using month and letter as Criteria's

Tags: excel, date, countif

I have a list of sales data that includes the date of the sale and also a sales type code. I'm trying to use COUNTIFS to count how many sales of a specific type there were during each month .

So for example:

```
Date.                  Sales Type Code
10/01/2014.                 S
12/01/2014.                 S
15/01/2014.                 O
18/01/2014.                 S
02/02/2014.                 O
08/02/2014.                 S
```

Would give me the following results:

```
Code S

January -       3    
February -      1

Code O

January -       1
February -      1
```

I have the formula

```
COUNTIFS('SALES LEDGER'!A:A,F2,'SALES LEDGER'!C:C,"<"&EOMONTH('MONTH Sales by Sales Type'!$C$1,0)+1)
```

Where A:A is the list of Sales Type Codes, F2 is the code I want to count, C:C is the list of dates and C1 is the first of the month I want to count (ie. 01/01/2014).

This works fine for January, giving me the expected result. But when I change C1 to 01/02/2014, it counts January **and** February together, rather than just February.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, is that Excel? Or you want it in other formats/ language programs?

Comment: @Llopis Yes that's excel - sorry should have said!

Comment: Do you expect your solution in Excel formulas? Or just to handle this problem in this formula. Or with another script with another programming language to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `COUNTIFS` formula specifies an end date but no start date, if you want to count for a specific month and year (based on C1) you need another criterion to specify the start date using C1, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS('SALES LEDGER'!A:A,F2,'SALES LEDGER'!C:C,"<"&EOMONTH('MONTH Sales by Sales Type'!$C$1,0)+1,'SALES LEDGER'!C:C,">="&'MONTH Sales by Sales Type'!$C$1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this one (if your range with dates doesn't contain empty cells):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A100)=1)*(B2:B100="S"))
```

or (if your range could contain empty cells)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(A2:A100,"mmm")="Jan")*(B2:B100="S"))
```

If you need to add also year condition, just add `*(YEAR(A2:A100)=2014)` in any formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(A2:A100,"mmm")="Jan")*(YEAR(A2:A100)=2014)*(B2:B100="S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

with the code below you can retrieve the month each date is in:

```
dim objDate as Date
dim i as integer
dim intMonth as integer

for i = 2 to 'number of row
    objDate = CDate(cells(i, 1))
    intMonth = Month(objDate)
next i
```

After figuring out the month with a simple loop you can count the number of sales in each month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- it is amenable to use helper columns
- Dates in col A
- Sale Type Codes in col B
- Results placed from A9:C11

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Add a helper col C to extract Month from date. Add this formula in C2 and drag down:

```
=TEXT(A2,"Mmm")
```

Add this formula in B10 and drag down and across:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$7,B$9,$C$1:$C$7,$A10)
```